# how to select lines with condition and save them in a file

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to write a program that opens a text file with only numbers in rows and columns, to save them in a new file. 
The part where I select columns works, while the part of the rows don't.
I must select the lines with the condition x > 10e13 (where x is the value in a specific column).
This is the code I have written:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.loadtxt('file.dat') 

#select columns:
column_indecies = [0] 
selected_columns = matrix[:,column_indecies]

x=10E13

#select lines:
for line in matrix:
   if float(line) > x:
       selected_lines = line

selected_matrix = matrix[selected_lines,selected_columns]

# output:
np.savetxt('new_file.dat', selected_matrix, fmt='%1.4f')
```

And this is the output error on terminal:

```
 selected_matrix = matrix[selected_lines]
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

I'm a beginner, can anyone help me? I'm a Mac user and I'm using python 2.7.
This is a small sample of my input data:

```
185100000000000.0000
121300000000000.0000
257800000000000.0000
43980000000000.0000
```

Comment: `if float(line) > x:` this is the reason for the error, also add a tab space for `selected_lines[] = line[]` line

Comment: I know, but how can i fix it? @NarenMurali

Comment: @AlessandroPeca add a colon after `x` and indent the next line by four spaces

Comment: @MoeA ok for the indent. But What do you mean with add a colon?

Comment: @AlessandroPeca `if float(line) > x:` <-- add a colon `:` after `x`

Comment: Nobody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a for loop.  Instead:

```
column = matrix[:,0]

x = 10E13

selected = column > x # this is a bool array

selected_matrix = column[selected]
```

Ref: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html

Comment: it's a good idea but gives me the error: `column = matrix[:,0] IndexError: too many indices for array`

Comment: It's for very big files, and I have been advised to use bumpy, can this be the problem?

Comment: @AlessandroPeca: You said in your question that the part where you select columns works.  And I have basically copied that part.  And now you say it does not work.  I guess your input data is not suitable, or you actually don't have anything working yet? Maybe post a small sample of your input data.

Comment: Yes, because I wrote another code just for columns, and it works ... I write the same lines.